# What is the best algorithm for closest word

Tags: algorithm

What is the best algorithm for closest word.

Possible word dictionary is given and first characters in the input word can be wrong.

Comment: Why only the first characters can be wrong?

Comment: Could you first give your definition of "closest"?

Comment: I mean first characters can be wrong.

Comment: closest word will be the word which has minimum edit distance from input to possible correct word.

Comment: Avinash: Below, you rejected Levenshtein as "slow".  So your idea of "best" must include performance, too, no?

Comment: So you don't mean that the first characters can be wrong, you also mean that middle characters or end characters can be wrong, unless you have some special definition of edit distance...

Comment: I think the point of that wording was to specifically exclude algorithms like Russell Soundex that require the first letter to match.  He didn't say that the middle/end characters *can't* be wrong.

Comment: How do you define edit distance? Should keyboard placement be taken into account? Qwerty? Phone? Seriously need more info here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is BK-trees - see my blog post about them [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees). Another, faster but more complex option is Levenshtein Automata, which I've also written about, [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata).

Comment: I am using Hunspell, and it returns 10 results like "hole", "hello", "help",  "hero" etc when I input "helo". I am expecting only "hello", something Google does when I search for "helo". Now is this based on statistical data as well, or just edit distance can suffice to suggest only "hello"?

Answer (score 4):

There are tools such as HunSpell (open-source spell-checker widely including OpenOffice) which have approached the problem from multiple perspectives. One widely used criterion for deciding how close the words are is [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is also used in HunSpell.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [BLAST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST)

and modify it to use the fact that words in a dictionary are discrete units which makes the process of matching more specific unlike a long DNA string.

BLAST already has built into it the notion of edit distances.

Alternatively, you could use suffix trees (Dan Gusfeld has an excellent book on basic string matching algorithms) and build in the idea of edit distances in.