# Compare input with List<String> , tell the user if input is correct, almost correct or wrong

Tags: java, for-loop, hashmap

I am new to java, so I apologies if the code makes your eyes bleed.
I am to make a simple "glossary test" in Swedish to English.

I have used hashmap to store the dictionary. The problems I have is when to compare user input with the correct translations.

I have created a for loop that loops through the array of translations. In that loop I would like to check the users input with the strings in that array and store correctans (number of correct answers) and I (how many questions that have been asked).

I can't get the correctans and I to update correctly.

Also I have trouble finding a good way to compare input with the string to check correctness.

My code :

```
import java.util.*;

    public class MyClass {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Mainmenu();
            getDictionary();
        }

        private static void Mainmenu() {
            System.out.println("** GLOSÖVNING-ENGELSKA **");
            System.out.println("Write the English word for the given Swedish. Quit by pressing Q ");
         //   System.out.println("the dictionary is : " + getDictionary()); // to see that the dictionary is correct
        }

        private static Map<String, List<String>> getDictionary() {

            Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
            String[][] dictionary = {
                    // Swedish, Translation1, Translation2, ...
                    {"bil", "car"},
                    {"snäll", "kind"},
                    {"kör", "drives", "choir"},
                    {"hej", "hello"},
                    {"äpple", "apple"},
                    {"kort", "short"}

            };
            for (String[] entry : dictionary) {
                String sweWord = entry[0]; // E.g. "kör"
                List<String> translations = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 1; i < entry.length; i++) {    // skips the first (swedish) word
                    translations.add(entry[i]); // e.g. "drives"

                }
                map.put(sweWord, translations);
                Querywords(map, sweWord, translations);
            }

            return map;
        }
// The swedish words asked
        private static List<String> Querywords(Map<String, List<String>> map, String sweWord, List<String> translations) {
            System.out.println(sweWord + ":");
            List<String> translation = Translation(sweWord, translations, map);
            return translation;
        }
// The correct answer/answers.
        private static List<String> Translation(String sweWord, List<String> translation, Map map) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inputString = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            int correctans=0;


            // add: to quit when Q is pressed
            for (int i=0; i < translation.size(); i++)  {
                boolean correct = translation.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(inputString);
                if (correct == true) {
                    correctans++;
                    System.out.println(translation.get(i));
                 //   System.out.println(translation+"translation"+i); for me to se that the code knows the right answer(s)..
                    System.out.println("Correct! " + correctans + "of " + i + " questions.");
                } else {

                    System.out.println("wrong"); //more code


                }

            }
            return translation;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest that your glossary not be a two dimensional array, but an array of glossary items, with one string and one array or list of translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the number of questions, just use the size of map as you are allowing user to enter the answers for all your keys in the dictionaries and for your count issue, please find simple code snippet. you can use as below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Dict {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int correct=0;
    
        System.out.println("** GLOSÖVNING-ENGELSKA **");
        System.out.println("Write the Swedish word for the given English. Quit by pressing Q ");
        
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        
        List<String> setone = new ArrayList<String>();
        setone.add("bil");
        setone.add("vagn");
        setone.add("godsfinka");
      
        List<String> settwo = new ArrayList<String>();
        settwo.add("slag");
        settwo.add("snall");
        
        List<String> setthree = new ArrayList<String>();
        setthree.add("halla");
        setthree.add("Hoy");
      
        map.put("car", setone);
        map.put("kind", settwo);
        map.put("hello", setthree);
        
        
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
        
            System.out.println(key +":");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String inputString = scanner.nextLine().trim();
            if (entry.getValue().contains(inputString)){
            correct++;
            System.out.println("Correct!" + correct + "of" + map.size());
            } else {
            System.out.println("Wrong!" + correct + "of" + map.size());
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Two things I still need some help with. If a swish word has two correct translations. How do I get the for loop to go through all of the translations? Also, how can I know if the input is almost correct? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: @farmacreds: I think that's what the above code does. For English word 'car' if the user enters 'bil' or 'vagn' or 'godsfinka', it will say correct. If the user inputs any other value, it would say wrong. I didn't get your second question. What do you mean by almost correct? Can you elaborate with some example?

Comment: When I copy and run the code given above and give "vagn" for the english word "car" I get "Wrong".. hmmm. What I mean by almost correct: Since it's a glossary test, if the user gives "vugn" instead of "vagn" for the english word "car" I want the output to be " almost correct!". So some how make the input into char string and compare to each char in the correct translation and count them. Lets say 30% of the inputs chars is wrong, that's to consider as almost right. I hope you understand what I mean. I don't know how to do this correctly.

Comment: Oops! I think I posted the wrong one! I have edited the code. You can use entry.getValue().contains(inputString) condition to check if the value you are searching is in the list of map values.

Comment: There are algorithms for determining strings that are close to an English word. I cannot remember the name, though.

Comment: Hope this link has answer to your second question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603760/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-closest-word

Comment: Isn´t there a simple way to make the translations into chars and compare it char by char with inputstring? Then I can add a counter that counts the amount of correct chars that the user gives compared to the correct translations.